# Material UI sub drawer from main drawer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am struggling to find an example of a "sub" drawer that extends a main drawer from Material UI. https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#drawer

I found this example of placing the drawer in a div (not the page) which can be adapted I think: [Is there a way to show a Material-UI Drawer nested inside a Grid component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749947/is-there-a-way-to-show-a-material-ui-drawer-nested-inside-a-grid-component).

The expected behaviour would be a button or event on the main drawer that can open the sub drawer. Here is a screenshot example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared an example for nested drawer in material ui. In this example, you can open a drawer on left. After opening it, you find a button `Show Nested Drawer` and if you click on that button you will have another drawer.

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import {makeStyles, useTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
    },
    appBar: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
    },
    appBarShift: {
        width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        marginLeft: drawerWidth,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    hide: {
        display: 'none',
    },
    drawer: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0,
    },
    drawerPaper: {
        width: drawerWidth,
    },
    drawerHeader: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
        // necessary for content to be below app bar
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    },
    content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
        marginLeft: -drawerWidth,
    },
    contentShift: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
        marginLeft: 0,
    },
}));

export default function NestedDrawerExample() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [subDrawerOpen, setSubDrawerOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        setDrawerOpen(true);
    };

    const handleDrawerClose = () => {
        setDrawerOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline/>
            <AppBar
                position="fixed"
                className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
                    [classes.appBarShift]: drawerOpen,
                })}
            >
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="open drawer"
                        onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
                        edge="start"
                        className={clsx(classes.menuButton, drawerOpen && classes.hide)}
                    >
                        <MenuIcon/>
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                        Nested Drawer Example
                    </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <Drawer
                className={classes.drawer}
                variant="persistent"
                anchor="left"
                open={drawerOpen}
                classes={{
                    paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                }}
            >
                <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
                    <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                        {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon/> : <ChevronRightIcon/>}
                    </IconButton>
                </div>
                <Divider/>
                <List>
                    {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
                        <ListItem button key={text}>
                            <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon/> : <MailIcon/>}</ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary={text}/>
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
                </List>
                <Divider/>
                <Button onClick={() => {
                    setSubDrawerOpen(true)
                }}>Open Nested Drawer</Button>
                <Drawer
                    className={classes.drawer}
                    variant="persistent"
                    anchor="left"
                    open={subDrawerOpen}
                    classes={{
                        paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                    }}
                >
                    <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
                        <IconButton onClick={()=>{setSubDrawerOpen(false) }}>
                            {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon/> : <ChevronRightIcon/>}
                        </IconButton>
                    </div>
                    <Divider/>
                    <List>
                        {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
                            <ListItem button key={text}>
                                <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon/> : <MailIcon/>}</ListItemIcon>
                                <ListItemText primary={text}/>
                            </ListItem>
                        ))}
                    </List>
                </Drawer>
            </Drawer>
            <main
                className={clsx(classes.content, {
                    [classes.contentShift]: drawerOpen,
                })}
            >
                <div className={classes.drawerHeader}/>
                <Typography paragraph>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </Typography>
                <Typography paragraph>
                    Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla
                    facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac
                    tincidunt.
                </Typography>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Khabir, in your example the nested drawer slides on top of the first drawer. This isn't what Im looking for. I am looking for the second drawer to open at the end of the first drawer so they sit side by side.

Comment: `Material ui` drawer is opened on left/right/top/bottom side. I am afraid `material-ui` supports what your requirement is or not

Comment: In this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c2adpk?embed=1&file=MakeshiftDrawer.js (from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749947/is-there-a-way-to-show-a-material-ui-drawer-nested-inside-a-grid-component) - they managed to open the drawer from within a div, the same concept could apply to the edge of another drawer. This should be possible?

Comment: That example does not  2 drawers side by side

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adjusting margins of second Drawer greater than width of first drawer.
a working example is here.
[CodeSandbox for Double Drawer]
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-clarke-142srj?file=/src/DoubleDrawer.jsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Drawer} from '@mui/material';

export default function App() {
  const [DrawerState, setDrawerState] = useState(false);
  const [DrawerState2, setDrawerState2] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div onClick={() => { setDrawerState(true); }}> some element to open first drawer </div>

  <Drawer anchor='left' open={DrawerState} onClose={() => { setDrawerState(false); }} BackdropProps={{ invisible: true }}
    sx={{
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
        width: '200px', height: '100%', boxSizing: 'border-box', backgroundColor: "black",
      }
    }}>
    <div onClick={() => { setDrawerState2(true); }}>
      <span> click here to go to next drawer </span>
    </div>
  </Drawer>
  <Drawer anchor='left' open={DrawerState2} onClose={() => { setDrawerState2(false); setDrawerState(false); }} BackdropProps={{ invisible: true }}
    sx={{
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
        width: '100px', height: '100%', boxSizing: 'border-box', marginLeft: '205px', backgroundColor: "white",
      }
    }}>
    <div>
      <span> Some element on second drawer </span>
    </div>
  </Drawer>
</div>
  );
};
```

[image]